Show $\int_X f \, d\mu \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_X f_n \, d\mu $ for non-negative functions
Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions such that $ f_n \geq 0 $ and $ f_n \to f $ in measure. Prove that $
\int_X f \, d\mu \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_X f_n \, d\mu.
$
By the F.Riesz theorem, there is a subsequence $\{f_{nk}\}$ converge to $f$ almost everywhere. Then by the DCT theorem, $\int_X f \, d\mu= \int_X \liminf_{k \to \infty}f_{nk} \, d\mu$, since $\liminf_{k \to \infty}f_{nk}= \lim_{k \to \infty}f_{nk}$. The Fatou's lemma shows that $
\int_X \liminf_{k \to \infty} f_{nk} \, d\mu \leq \liminf_{k \to \infty} \int_X f_{nk} \, d\mu.
$ But I don't know whether $
 \liminf_{k \to \infty} \int_X f_{nk} \, d\mu=\liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_X f_{n} \, d\mu$. How to prove they are equal? If they are not equal, could you give some hints?

You're almost there, just one small thing - you shouldn't take an arbitrary subsequence $f_{n_k}$, but take $f_{n_k}$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_X f_{n_k}d\mu=\liminf \int_X f_n$, and then take a subsequence $f_{n_{k_j}}$ such that $f_{n_{k_j}}\to f$ a.e. Also, you can't use DCT (since it is not given that $f_n$ are uniformly bounded by some integrable function), but just use Fatou's lemma:
$$\int_X fd\mu=\int_X\lim_{j\to\infty}f_{n_{k_j}}\leq \liminf_ {j\to\infty}\int_Xf_{n_{k_j}}=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_Xf_nd\mu$$
